# ReactJs component architecture

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

i am asking this question to understand better how to implement using react js.

i am just getting started with react js (so excuse me if this question is rather stupid)

for much of the tutorial that i see, i have noticed that everything in the web page is defined as component, also when part of the page can be static html.

i want to know if this is the best approach, or if it's better to just insert my react components only inside DIV's that have some "dynamic data"/user interaction.

i have a couple things in mind

- place some static HTML when needed, just to show something very fast to the user before any data arrived
- that way i can show placeholders using static html, before rendering components
- if its ok also to place some static HTML, will it work with react server side rendering (we are using PHP as a server)

thank you

Comment: You can use React as much or as little as you want. Some people write entire web applications with it, others use it for only a single component on a page of otherwise static HTML.

Comment: You can't run React server side with PHP, it run with Node JS. If you want a simple architecture youc an check my personal project: https://github.com/DWboutin/Beverage/

Answer (score 1):

I personally avoid mixing and matching architectures, for the sake of simplicity. My point being, that I want the design to be consistent within my app, rather than doing certain things one way, and others another way.

When you mention "before any data has arrived" are you referring to an ajax call? If so, this is a great way to do it: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

This will allow the page to render before the ajax call has been submitted, but will automatically update it once the data is available (something that react does a great job at). By doing so, I would also avoid using static html (placing html in an html file, rather than inside the jsx).

Comment: hey thanks. its a bit confusing. since the browser know best, and also the fastest way to render html, i am struggling with that a bit. this why i am fighting with rendering react on the server using PHP (i am forced to a wed server). 
what is the advantages of using the entire site as JSX components ?

Comment: The biggest advantage is going to be code maintainability. What are you trying to render that makes you concerned with speed of html vs javascript?

Comment: simple, i am trying to display something as soon as possible. showing something before any JS compiling/fetching data. for a faster user expirience

Comment: The link that I provided will allow you to render the base state before data is fetched. Basically, you would execute an ajax call inside of componentDidMount(), which would then update the state with the data that was retrieved. On any call to setState(), react will automatically and selectively re-render components. Rendering the base state will cover ~99% of use cases.